# How to reset all controls value in a specific form

Tags: jquery

here i got a script which reset form controls data but it is for all the form, if i need to reset a specific form then how could i do it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function resetFields(form) {
            $(':input', form).each(function() {
                var type = this.type;
                var tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase(); // normalize case
                // to reset the value attr of text inputs,
                // password inputs, fileUpload and textareas
                if (type == 'text' || type == 'password' || tag == 'textarea' || type=='file')
                    this.value = "";
                // checkboxes and radios need to have their checked state cleared                
                else if (type == 'checkbox' || type == 'radio')
                    this.checked = false;
                // select elements need to have their 'selectedIndex' property set to -1
                // (this works for both single and multiple select elements)
                else if (tag == 'select')
                    this.selectedIndex = 0;
            });
        }

    </script>
```

where to change in the above script.

Comment: you need to call it by passing some parameter it  is not for every form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an `id` to your form

```
<form id="my_form" ...>...</form>
```

and then call the given function passing the form like this:

```
$('#reset_button').on('click', function() {
    resetFields($('#my_form'));
});
```

Your function goes through all the fields within the passed form and resets their values.